# How to fix visual studio projects unable to open

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have Windows System(OS 10), I installed Visual Studio 12 and 17 versions and SQL SERVER 2014. Unfortunately, when I am trying to open projects in vs2012/17 it is closing immediately after clicking on an open project or new Project creation. I observed another thing System IIS also not working properly. I am unable to find the reason.

Comment: Do you use team explorer for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

- Open visual Studio
- Connect to your team project in Team Explorer
- Open the project you wanted initialy to open. This can **either be done
  by File -> Open -> Project/Solution or by selecting the project from
  the recent tab.**

Answer (score 0):

Check %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\ActivityLog.xml location for errors